# How to get a file reading stream from an s3 bucket?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, multipartform-data

There is an external REST API that I interact with via axios. It accepts an image in *multipart/form-data* format as input. When I try to send from my computer using the following code, everything works!

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('photo', fs.createReadStream(imgPath));

const uploadImgResult = await request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: upload_url,
  headers: formData.getHeaders(),
  data: formData
});
```

But now I am faced with the task of doing the same from AWS lambda function, receiving an image from s3 Bucket. I tried several options for getting the read stream, but they all return an incorrect file type error.

I understand that based on the example above, I need to figure out how to get the s3 from the file in a format so that it can be added to the form. And here are the options I tried:

```
// Option 1
this._awsS3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});    
const imgObject = await this._awsS3
        .getObject({
            Key: requestParams.key,
            Bucket: 'someBucketName'
         })).promise();

// Option 2
const imgObject = this._awsS3
        .getObject({
            Key: requestParams.key,
            Bucket: 'someBucketName'
         }))
        .createReadStream();

// Option 3
const imgObject await (new Promise(async res => {
        const passThroughStream = new PassThrough();

        this._awsS3
            .getObject({
               Key: requestParams.key,
               Bucket: 'someBucketName'
            })
            .createReadStream().pipe(passThroughStream);

        passThroughStream.on('finish', () => {
            res(passThroughStream);
        }));
```

It is important to note that the files are stored in s3 in the form of correct png images (I tried downloading them manually, they open). Also, all of the above methods successfully retrieve a file from s3 in one form or another. The only problem is that the API endpoint returns an type error